# niginx proxy_pass no longer passing the real IP

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I have this setup for years: centos5, nginx, apache
Nginx is configured to proxy like this

`proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;`

I don't know what happened, or what I may have done somewhere, but suddenly a little over a month ago, the setup stopped working: as in apache is getting the local IP of the proxy instead of the actual real IP of the client.
I just noticed it today, which is why I don't know what I may have done. I tracked back the http logs where I have the client IP logged and that's how I know the date and time this change occurred.
Yum logs don't show anything around that date.
I made the mistake of first trying some configurations before looking at the config file timestamps, so that info is lost. But I don't think I changed the config.

Any ideas what may have gone wrong?

I did try replacing the x-forwarded-for with

`proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;`

and also added 

    `set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.3;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive on;`

at the top of my http config in nginx.conf, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, it seems the issue was caused by some IP related changes somewhere.
(background: both nginx and apache are on the same server.)

Specifically, the mod_rpaf configuration was having RPAF_ProxyIPs 127.0.0.1 since 2016 when I set it up.
But somehow, at beginning of April, the server got to communicate with apache not on 127.0.0.1 but on the LAN IP of the server (192.168.0.3)
Adding that to RPAF_ProxyIPs sp;ved the problem.